# How to verify if user has no password privileges for specific commands using sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I'm writing a bash script that uses the `sudo` command on LINUX to automate the process of mounting and extracting media from an ISO image.  As one of the requirements, the script should not require a user to enter their password.  Consequently, I've edited the `sudoers` file so that the specified user has no password access privileges to the `mount` and `umount` commands on Linux.

However, I was wondering if there was a way for my bash script to detect whether the user has no password sudo privileges for the `mount` and `umount` commands so that it can exit gracefully in the event that the `sudoers` file has not been configured.

I've thought about using `sudo -l` to look at the user's sudo privileges; however, this command requires a password.  Furthermore, `sudo -n true` does not appear to be working either. As a result, I was wondering if another method for checking the user's sudo privileges exists without having to parse the `sudoers` file.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? That gives these users power to mount/umount other volumes, too. Whereas, if your `/etc/fstab` is set up right, you can allow users to mount/umount specific volumes (see the `user` option).

Comment: For the purposes of deployment, giving the specific user mount access rights using sudo will be okay.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo -n true` appears to work as advertised for me; it displays an error message and exits with a non-zero exit code.  I guess `sudo -n mount` would be the command you actually want, though.

Comment: The issue is that with the version of OPENSUSE I'm using, it does not appear to support sudo -n...